# how can i manipulate the space between each card in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make them closer like the picture that is attached. How can I change that property?

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

I need them to be more close with one another and to make them in the center of the page but I find it hard to do. I've tried the column-gap but its not working. please help this is my first time.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't put sizes on the cards. Use the grid to control sizing.
2. Rows require containers around them.
3. Don't use inline styles. That makes work harder for everyone, and much of what you might do with it can be done with Bootstrap features anyway. If you need custom styles, use a custom class.
4. The [center element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) is deprecated. Don't use it. Use Bootstrap's [text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/text/#text-alignment) or [flex layout features](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content) instead.

```css
.col.mw-16_5 {
  max-width: 16.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col mw-16_5">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col mw-16_5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col mw-16_5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col mw-16_5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All that said, you might just want to use basic [flexbox layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/) instead of rows and columns. You can use Bootstrap's [margin classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) for card spacing.

```css
.card.minw-10 {
  min-width: 10rem;
}

.card.maxw-16_5 {
  max-width: 16.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
  <div class="card m-2 minw-10 maxw-16_5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card m-2 minw-10 maxw-16_5">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card m-2 minw-10 maxw-16_5">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card m-2 minw-10 maxw-16_5">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card m-2 minw-10 maxw-16_5">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card m-2 minw-10 maxw-16_5">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem; margin-left: 20px;>
```

i use px but you can use rem, cm, etc.

Comment: Inline styles are poor practice, and Bootstrap has mechanisms for spacing, column gutters, etc. built in.

Comment: my answer is based on the questions, he/she used inline css.